# Trouble with package glmulti

Tags: r, aic

I try to install and use the glmulti function from the glmulti package

```
install.packages('glmulti')
library(glmulti)
```

But I am seeing no function called glmulti. Could anyone else please test and let me know if I am missing something obvious? Currently when I call the function I get the following error (note reduced specs to reduce clutter):

```
Error in glmulti(...  : 
  could not find function "glmulti"
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I just removed the specs to reduce clutter. Should have specified.

Comment: It appears to be properly installed. Are you saying I need to install rJava independently? Why is it a pain to install?

Comment: ok it works for me.. i just installed and run the function. Are you sure it is installed? when you do library(glmulti), it doesn't throw an error? Mine shows this ```library(glmulti)
Loading required package: rJava ```

Comment: Ugh. Narrow console means I only saw the version error messages...

```Loading required package: rJava
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry
Error: package ‘rJava’ could not be loaded```

Any thoughts on why it is failing? If I manually install rJava on its own, I still get an error.

Comment: Just googled the separate issue that is getting rJava to work. I'm on it and will post my fix shortly. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to StupidWolf for pointing out solution in the comments.

I required 64-bit Java available from this [link](https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp) (current 27/04/2020).

Restart R and reload packages and *voila!*